# Flexible and customized tables using svg

Tags: python, html, svg, probability

When representing conditionnal probabilities (P(X|Y,Z,...), one has to deal with large tables of numbers (aka CPTs). PyAgrum (a python package) use html in notebooks to obtain a quite good representation of these CPTs :

[image: different CPTs]

The size, the number of columns in the headers, bgcolors of cells, etc. have to be very flexible. HTML table are very usefool tool to do this job. However HTML representation is not easy to export and to use outside a notebook.

So I am looking for ideas to do the same job but either in SVG or PDF or other.